# Getting the Column data from html data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the all the column value of a th. For eg in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtco5yae/1/) when I visit th then i want to get all td in that column.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tableizer-table th').each(function(index,val){

       $('.tableizer-table tr td').eq(index).each(function (index,value) {
        console.log(value);
       });


  });
  });
```

Above code isn't working.

Comment: how and when you want the data?

Comment: @Thinker when I visit th then I want to get all the values underneath that th. For eg in above html when i visit 'Item# ' then i want to get all column values underneath it  that are 'Alloy (HR) Cast - HA (10 Cr Bal Fe) (CPO) Metal_Alloy' and others.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you data per column, but it would be nice to know the required end-result, as @Thinker has asked about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tableizer-table th').each(function(index,val){
    console.log(index);
    $('.tableizer-table tr').each(function() {
       console.log($($(this).find('td')[index]).text())
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I want that but do you know that how could I get td without the td just text only? Currently its coming <td>​Alloy (HR) Cast - HA (10 Cr Bal Fe) (CPO)​</td>​ . I would like to only have text in that td. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can get it the data according to the column like this

**(Note: you will get the data when you click a th)**

```js
$('.tableizer-table th').click(function() {
  var getData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $(".tableizer-table tbody tr").length; i++) {
getData.push($(".tableizer-table tbody tr td").eq($(this).index()).text());
  }
  alert(getData)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableizer-table display cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <th>Item#</th>
    <th>Family</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Characteristics</th>
    <th>Full Description</th>
    <th>Format</th>
    <th>UOM</th>
    <th> Price </th>
    <th>Updated</th>
    <th>Source</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HA (10 Cr Bal Fe) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $0.192 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HC (26 Cr, 4 Ni) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $0.556 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HD (26 Cr 6 Ni) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $0.647 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HE (26 Cr 10 Ni) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $0.848 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HF (20 Cr 10 Ni) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $0.789 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HH (25 Cr, 12 Ni ) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $0.935 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HI (26 Cr, 5 Ni) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $1.090 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alloy (HR) Cast - HK (25 Cr, 20 Ni ) (CPO)</td>
      <td>Metal_Alloy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Heat-Resistant Casting Alloys (Price based on item's commodity ingredients only. No processing)</td>
      <td>Market Price of components</td>
      <td>USD/LB</td>
      <td> $1.323 </td>
      <td>10/23/15</td>
      <td>MetalPricing.com (CPO)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you hover or visit a column header, you want all the td element's under that column to be written into the console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tableizer-table th').on('hover', function(){
        var columnIndex = $(this).parent().index($(this));

        $('.tableizer-table tbody tr').each(function() {
            console.log($(this).children('td').eq(columnIndex).text());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want html, but only text?

Use `$(this).text()` instead of `value` in `.each()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign a unique class name to the cells you want then extract the entire class with one call:

```
    $('.mycolumnX')
```

Then you can just loop through the results in the array.